# Use Dynamic Array Output of Excel FILTER Function in Include Argument of Another FILTER Function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two Excel Tables across which I want to filter some data, using dynamic array results from FILTERing one table to FILTER a second table. Here is a simplified example - the first table is labeled as **HelperTable** and is used to get back an array of relevant SEQs based on a CATEGORY:

| SEQ | CATEGORY |
| --- | --- |
| 32 | Fruit |
| 33 | Vegetable |
| 34 | Fruit |
| 35 | Vegetable |

I also have a table called **DataTable** which contains some broader data, including SEQs but not CATEGORY:

| INDEX | SEQ | DEPARTMENT | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 14 | Blue | 45689 |
| 1 | 32 | Blue | 23749 |
| 2 | 32 | Red | 23892 |
| 3 | 25 | Red | 32981 |

From the second table I want to logically filter the formula equivalent of "VALUE when DEPARTMENT is Blue and SEQ is from CATEGORY Fruit in HelperTable," which based on the table should return 23749.

So I can do `FILTER(HelperTable[SEQ],HelperTable[CATEGORY]="Fruit")` and get {32, 34}, spilled over two cells, but then I don't know how to nest that result in the encapsulating FILTER:
`FILTER(DataTable[VALUE], (DataTable[DEPARTMENT]="Blue")*(DataTable[SEQ]=OTHER_FILTER_RESULT))`

Answer (score 1):

Use ISNUMBER(MATCH()) where the values to search is `HelperTable[SEQ]` and the array to be searched is the return of your first filter: `FILTER(HelperTable[SEQ],HelperTable[CATEGORY]="Fruit")`

```
=FILTER(DatTable[VALUE],(DatTable[DEPARTMENT]="Blue")*(ISNUMBER(MATCH(DatTable[SEQ],FILTER(HelperTable[SEQ],HelperTable[CATEGORY]="Fruit"),0))))
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, that causes the right kind of "array matrix multiplication" I see. I had to 0 to match type to get exact results but otherwise this checked out!

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to stick to making `FILTER` work, the following will do the trick:

```
=FILTER(  FILTER(D2:G5,F2:F5="Blue"),  IFERROR(  MATCH(  FILTER(E2:E5,F2:F5="Blue"),  FILTER(A2:A9,B2:B9="Fruit"),  0),  0)  )
```

The second (first "inner") `FILTER` gets the records matching "Blue" and that array is the input to the first ("outer") `FILTER`.

To build the outer `FILTER`'s keep/discard array ({FALSE;TRUE} or {0;1} in this case), `MATCH`'s first `FILTER` gets the successful sequence numbers that appear in the above `FILTER` by going back to the original data, not the above `FILTER`. The second `FILTER` in the `MATCH` function makes an array of the appropriate matches to the helper table's data, and `MATCH`... matches the successful data's sequence numbers to those. Notice that all these returns are ROWS, hence the `;` in the first sentence's keep/discard array.

Now the outer `FILTER` has a result for its selection of records based upon color and an array for deciding which to display that is built from the same data it was, but that is independent of it, so there is no difficulty matching the two. (Which is the biggest difficulty causer when using `FILTER` to sub-filter. One usually ends up using a range of some number of rows, say 100, and returns, say, 38 of them, but the keep/discard array gets based upon that return and now your source size, 100, and your test size, 38, do not match so you get an error. This formula avoids that by building them separately so when finally used, both are the same size. Then it's just a matter of properly testing and converting the results into a {1;1;1;0;0;1;1;0;1;0;0;0;1} type of array.)

Just adding this to demonstrate `FILTER` will do these sub-filterings, or more exactly, one way it will. So long as you remember the array size match-up problem, you can do just that. Usually, a number of ways. This one can probably be improved upon, but there's no need as `Scott Craner`'s method is more easily extensible to more than two conditions, as one might easily encounter in everyday use.